# TypeError: message.guild.channels.find is not a function

Tags: discord.js

I get a certain error when I search for a channel.

Code:

```
let logschannel = message.guild.channels.find('name', "logs");
```

Error:

```
TypeError: message.guild.channels.find is not a function
```

I hope someone can help me! :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you're using outdated code. In discord.js version 12 `.channels` was changed. The equivalent line of code in version 12 would be:

```
    let logschannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'logs');
```

I would recommend looking at the [guide for updating discord.js code from v11 to v12](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#managers-cache)